# Replicate a tab in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template (named template in the code) and a list of store numbers ( named list in the code).  I want to create a new worksheet identical to the template, but replace one cell (E5) with the next number in the list.  I have this code but it doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas? :

```
Sub CreateNewSheet()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("List").Range("A2") 'Must change tab name
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets("List").Select
        MyCell.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
        Range("E5").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value & "-" ' renames the new worksheet
            Range("E5").Select 'Puts driver name in cell


    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the range for one thing here:

```
Set MyRange = Sheets("List").Range("A2") 'Must change tab name
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
```

When I think you want to actually create the range to loop over. Note  `MyRange.End(xlDown)` will take you down to the last non-blank cell in the range rather than the last used row.

So, I have changed your syntax to find the last row, stored in a variable, and use that to define the loop range.

```
    lastRow = ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

    Set MyRange = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
```

Then I have put the List worksheet in a variable so you don't need to go backwards and forward selecting sheets.

```
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
```

This means that whenever you add a sheet, which will become the activesheet, you  can simply refer access the MyCell value as it is qualified by the sheet name it came from.

This,

```
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value & "-"
```

Looks a bit dodgy in terms of naming. Sort of looks unfinished. However, that should be enough to get you going.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateNewSheet()

   Dim MyCell As Range
   Dim MyRange As Range
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim lastRow As Long

   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
   lastRow = ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

    Set MyRange = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    Dim counter

    For Each MyCell In MyRange

        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("E5") = MyCell
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value & "-" ' renames the new worksheet

    Next MyCell
End Sub
```